# load more button in instafeed js issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, instafeedjs

The load more btn works fine, but when i click load more, images are showing up but the problem is its shows from the top, it doesn't show where i was. it should show from 13 and the rest , not from img 1 and the rest.

HTML

```
   <a class="btn" href="#">load more</a>
```

Javascript

```
   function instafeed() {
   var myButton = $('#load-more');
   var brave = new Instafeed({
   target: 'brave',
   get: 'user',
   userId: XXXX,
   accessToken: 'XXXX',
   limit: 12,
   resolution: 'low_resolution',
   template: '<div class="insta-wrap grid"><img src="{{image}}" /><a class="grid-link" href="{{link}}"  target="_blank"><div class="likes-wrap"><div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></div></a></div>',
   after: function() {
    if (!this.hasNext()) {
        myButton.hide();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You might want to try using `#brave` as the target and ensuring there is a `<div id="brave"></div>` on the page.

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but you can check the options for instafeed http://instafeedjs.com/#standard. There is a sortBy options.

Comment: Can you share you click handler for your `$("#load-more")` button?